# XACML Fine Grained Authorization between WSO2 ESB- IS

Tags: authentication, authorization, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm working with the use case published on http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/10/using-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-wso2-platform/ and it works well but I need to customize the XACML query with Action, Resource and Subject fields.

When I add the Entitlement Mediator to ESB I am not able to add these arguments (which are stored in properties elements on ESB). How can I specify Action, Resource and Subject to construct the XCAML query before sending to IS?

Thanks in advance,

Joan

Answer (score 0):

In entitlement mediator has call back handler where you can implement a way to pick those Action, Resource and so on.  By default handler, picks as following

Resource  -->  Incoming message   "To"  soap header

Subject --->  if your proxy service is secured with UT and Basic auth,  it would pick the authenticated user name

But you can write your own handler and plug it with entitlement mediator,  there are some available handler implementations.  You can refer this [1] for more details

[1] http://nallaa.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/entitlement-mediator-with-wso2-enterprise-service-bus-esb/

Comment: Hi Asela and thanks for your help. I'm working with ESB last version 4.7.0 and I don't see options you are talking about (which also are published on http://nallaa.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/screenshot-from-2013-09-29-004551.png ). Please could you indicate me how I can set these options?

Comment: Sorry...  Some of the things are available with next ESB release..(4.8.0)

Comment: I guess there is no UI in 4.7.0 to configure this.  But stll you have all these options using synapse config.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use ESB 4.8.0 it would be release soon.  However there is no UI in 4.7.0 to configure them. But you can do it using synapse configuration.  Say you want to add new custom call back class. you can add it as follows